# Eina from EFL incompatible with ftw.h?

Tags: c, posix, efl

I tried to play with the file module of the Eina library and the classical system calls.
My problem is when I want to use eina and some functions and constants from ftw.h.

Here is the first simple code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 /*Get nftw() and S_IFSOCK declarations*/              
#include <ftw.h>                                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
#include <Eina.h>                                                               
/*Compile with                                                                  
gcc -o eina_ftw eina_ftw.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags eina)                   
*/                                                                              
int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                 
{                                                                               
  int a = FTW_DNR;                                                              
  int b=0;                                                                      
  b = FTW_MOUNT;                                                                
  printf("ok\n");                                                               
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);                                                           
}
```

When I compile it I have those errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/eina-1/eina/eina_lock.h:50:0,
                 from /usr/include/eina-1/Eina.h:259,
                 from eina_ftw.c:5:
 /usr/include/eina-1/eina/eina_inline_lock_posix.x:57:1: erreur: unknown type name   thread_spinlock_t’
typedef pthread_spinlock_t Eina_Spinlock;
^
/usr/include/eina-1/eina/eina_inline_lock_posix.x:561:4: erreur: unknown type name ‘pthread_barrier_t’
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
^
```

Ok so I tried this:

```
#include <Eina.h>  
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 /*Get nftw() and S_IFSOCK declarations*/              
#include <ftw.h>                                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             

/*Compile with                                                                  
gcc -o eina_ftw eina_ftw.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags eina)                   
*/                                                                              
int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                 
{                                                                               
  int a = FTW_DNR;                                                              
  int b=0;                                                                      
  b = FTW_MOUNT;                                                                
  printf("ok\n");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);                                                           
}
```

And now I have this kind of error:

```
eina_ftw.c: In function ‘main’:
eina_ftw.c:13:7: erreur: ‘FTW_MOUNT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   b = FTW_MOUNT;
       ^
eina_ftw.c:13:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `_XOPEN_SOURCE 500` is (approximately equivalent to) asking for the 1995 POSIX declarations.

Set it to at least 600 (for POSIX 2001) or perhaps 700 (for POSIX 2008).

Strictly, of course, setting `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is asking for a particular version of the Open Group (originally X/Open) Single Unix Specification, but there is a strong relationship between the POSIX standard and the Open Group standard.  You can find out more at:

- [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, IEEE Std 1003.1™, 2013 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)
- [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6, IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/)
- [Single UNIX® Specification, Version 2, 1997](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/)